# Patch dynamic data to repeat type in angular-formly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formly

My goal is to patch external json data to a form which contains a FieldArrayType.

Say I have the following formly field config:

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'cars',
      type: 'repeat',
      fieldArray: {
        fieldGroupClassName: 'row',
        templateOptions: {
          btnText: 'Add',
        },
        fieldGroup: [
          {
            className: 'col-sm-4',
            type: 'input',
            key: 'type',
            templateOptions: {
              label: 'Type:'
            },
          },
          {
            type: 'input',
            key: 'name',
            className: 'col-sm-3',
            templateOptions: {
              label: 'Name:'
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
```

And later on I want to patch some data to this repeat type:

```
  patchData() {
    let data = {
      "cars":[
        {"type":"Type1","name":"Name1"},
        {"type":"Type2","name":"Name2"}]
      };

    // Failure: Only the first car value is patched, the second car is not patched
    // (unless) 'Add' is clicked first, which is not intended.
    this.form.patchValue(data);
  }
```

The problem is that at the initial load of the form, only one item is present in the repeat section. Therefore, if I patch data to the form which contains two or more items of the field array, only the first item is applied and stored in the model.

Is there a way to programmatically add items to the FieldArray before patching the data so the data is received by the model?

Note: The length of the data can vary.

Please see the following stackblitz as example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfykhx

Comment: So when you click the patch button , you want to append new controls in form . Am i right?

Comment: @vinodh that's right

Answer (score -1):

```js
  constructor(
       private fb: FormBuilder
     )
     
     patchData() {
      this.form=this.fb.group({
        cars:this.fb.array([])
      });
      
        let data = {
          "cars":[
            {"type":"Type1","name":"Name1"},
            {"type":"Type2","name":"Name2"}]
          };
        const fa = <FormArray>this.form.controls['cars'];
        data.cars.forEach((each)=>{
          let tFormGroup:FormGroup=this.fb.group({
            type:[each.type],
            name:[each.name]
          });
          tFormGroup.patchValue(each);
          fa.push(tFormGroup);
        })
      }
```

```html
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div formArrayName="cars">
        <div *ngFor="let car of form['controls'].cars;let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input ype="text" formControlName="type">
           <input ype="text" formControlName="name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```